# How to get number apps running in background

Tags: android, background, ram

I am working on an app which needs the information of how many application running in background at the system,
I want to get number of them.
Any idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Below lines give the list of Apps which are in background,

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

`procInfos.size()` gives you number of apps